# Why Factory insufficient for sorting?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I found this in a forum and it seems to be well explained:

> Strategy is a pattern aimed at allowing you to add new (in your case sort) algorithms to your software without breaking the clients of the algorithms. It's an investment in design complexity that will pay off if you need to add new algorithms without breaking your clients. Factory is a pattern that complements Strategy because the clients of the algorithm implementations should not know specifically which implementation they're using (in terms of software classes). The factory instantiates the concrete implementations of the algorithm so the client can use them without knowing the details.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

However i m not able to understand the need of SortStrategtyInterface.Should not we just ask factory to return the sort string.

Also if someone thing above is correct, then can they share the code to call this? Also with an example if I remove SortstrategyInterface, then what disadvantages it can have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the interface isn't exactly 'necessary', it's defiantly better to have one to assure a contract between the client and the different sort algorithms. This contract simply assures the client that the method 'getSortString()' is present in whichever strategy that is returned from the factory. From php5 the code would look something like this:

```
$sorting_obj = SortStrategyFactory::getSorterBy("demand");
if ( ! $sorting_obj instanceof SortStrategyInterface ) {
  throw new \exception('contract failed, the sorting algorithm must implement the SortStrategyInterface');
}
$sorting_obj->getSortString();

# or maybe:
try {
  $sorting_obj = (SortStrategyInterface)SortStrategyFactory::getSorterBy("date");
} catch ( \exception $e ) {
  # ...
}
$sorting_obj->getSortString();
```

Interface are never "really" needed, but their use certainly has a ton of advantages with no real disadvantage. Keeping contracts between clients and implementations makes extending so much simpler in the long run.

Comment: thanx bro :-)
can you help me explain why Strategy pattern is so important here.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy pattern (once again) isn't "necessary", it's simply a nice to have when its use fits your needs. The basic idea is that you can have multiple implementations for a common concept (sorting). Taking off from the same example posted above, the strategy pattern would allow you to add even more implementations of 'sort' without requiring changes to the existing client(s).

Let's imagine you receive a new requirement for a new "SortByUser", this new task will only require implementing a SortStrategyInterface with the method getSortString(), as well as a couple of lines in the factory for creating it. From there the old clients will have no unintended side effects and the new/modified clients will have access to this new sorting strategy. In my experience, strategy patterns are the ones that emerge naturally the most often. Whenever your original requirements ask for an 'alternative' (keyword) approach to a concept you can almost immediately think of a strategy pattern.

Comment: Awesome 
it means many time we are using strategy pattern and we are unaware of it :-)

thanx now i know i m using strategy pattern

Answer (score -1):

Strategy allow you to easily add algorithms at run time. For me factory should be enough, however as per theory, strategy + factory should suit you.